# Apply selectors on couples of elements of possibly infinite sequences C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable, yield-return

I have to implement an extension-method

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MyMerge<T1, T2, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T1> s1, IEnumerable<T2> s2, Func<T1, T2, TResult> f)
```

that returns the sequence f(x1,y1),f(x2,y2)... where all the xn are elements of s1 and all the yn are elements of s2.

My problem is that this sequence must have the same length of the shortest sequence and both s1 and s2 can be infinite. If they weren't so i could do

```
var res = new List<TResult>();
for (var i = 0; i<Math.Min(s1.Count(), s2.Count()) ; i++)
{
    res.Add(f(s1.ToArray()[i], s2.ToArray()[i]));
}
return res;
```

but this brokes also when one sequence is longer than the other. How can i resolve this?

Comment: In the code that you have, on every single iteration (which is to say for every item in the smallest sequence) you go through the *entirety* of *both* sequences to count their size, then you copy every single item in both sequences to new arrays in order to just pull out *one* item from each array.  That's going to be *extremely* inefficient.  Just copying the values into arrays *once* is problematic; doing it for every item you yield....

Comment: @Servy  Ehmm yes, let's say i've lot to improve about handling sequences :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET already has an implementation of this *exact* functionality, `Enumerable.Zip`.

As for how to implement it, if you wanted to do it yourself, it's fairly straightforward.  Get an `IEnumerator` for each enumerable, while both have another value apply the result selector on the two current values and `yield` that result.

Comment: Thanks, actually i didn't think to enumerators! I'm very grateful.